# send email using AWS SES smtp with meteor

Tags: meteor, meteorite, meteor-accounts

I am trying out to send email using aws ses using meteor.
My code at server end is:

```
import { Meteor } from 'meteor/meteor';
if(Meteor.isServer) {
Meteor.startup(function() {  
process.env.MAIL_URL="smtp://username:password@email-smtp.us-east-1.amazonaws.com:465"; 
Accounts.emailTemplates.from='abc@abc.com';
Accounts.emailTemplates.sitename='abc'; 
Accounts.emailTemplates.resetPassword.subject = function (user) {   
return "Password reset email" ;
};  
});
}
```

below is the error:

[image]

I have verified the sender email id.

Comment: Just a shot in the dark, but I seem to recall running into the same issue. I had to move the `process.env.MAIL_URL` assignment outside (above) the `Meteor.startup` block. For some reason the timing of setting it in the startup function was not early enough.

Comment: I am able to send emails using mailgun using the same syntax and format but for aws ses its throwing the above error.:(

Comment: still getting the error. :( moving the assignment did not work.

Comment: its working:  using a javascript console (chrome dev tools / firebug) run

encodeURIComponent("SES_SMTP_USERNAME")
encodeURIComponent("SES_SMTP_PASSWORD") use the above encoded value for setting the smtp url